# Symfony 3.4 and Doctrine events - is it possible to redirect the user if an exception is thrown?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, exception

I'm building an e-commerce site that talks to Stripe's API during a set of `prePersist`, `preUpdate`, and `preRemove` Doctrine events.  Unfortunately, the [documentation for Symfony events](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/event_dispatcher.html) doesn't really have anything on error/exception handling within events.

Ideally, I'd log the exception, and then redirect the user to a safe route (maybe the one that dispatched the event, or maybe a catch-all error page) with a relevant error message (flash message).  Is that possible?  If so, how would I do that from within an event?

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a custom Exception and catch it via a Exception Listener and handle the redirect there.

See [Symfony Events and Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html).

Just set the response of the Event to a RedirectResponse.